# Printing out the number of lines a file contains

Tags: java

At the moment my code does nothing when i input a valid .txt file. I would like to print the number of lines the file contains. Could anyone tell me why nothing is currently happening?

```
public class Task3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        // instance variables
        int characterCount = 0;
        int wordCount = 0;
        int lineCount = 0;
        // create a Scanner object to read in file name from console input
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the file name: ");
        String filename = in.next();
        File inputFile = new File(filename);


        // create a Scanner object to read the actual text file
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(inputFile);

        int lines = 0;

        while (inFile.hasNextLine())
        { // enter while loop if there is a complete line available
        in.nextLine();
            lines++;
            // increase line counter variable
            }
          System.out.println(lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not reading lines from the file, you're reading them from standard input.

Answer (score 1):

In this loop:

```
    while (inFile.hasNextLine())
    { // enter while loop if there is a complete line available
        in.nextLine();
        lines++;
        // increase line counter variable
    }
```

You are using the Scanner for `System.in`, not the scanner you created for the file. So the call to `nextLine` will wait for your input instead of going to the next line in the file. That's why it seems that nothing is happening.

Replace `in.nextLine` with `inFile.nextLine` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
in.nextLine();
```

To:

```
inFile.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a System.out.println(inputFile.exists()) to see that you are not creating a new file.